# Ajax Callback for jquery function

Tags: ajax, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC 4 project, it is some sort of evaluation tool.
On my view CoWorkers, i'm filling a datatable with the data requested from the database.
In the first column, I display the name, in the second column, i'm displaying a link to their personal files.
The View of that is in a partial called "PersoonlijkeFichePartial", so when i click on a link in the datatable, it has to open the partial in a div under the datatable. I do this with an ajax call.
But I the result div is empty, I dont want to see that in my view, so I did with jquery.
Now the problem is, when i click on the link in my datatable(with the ajax call), the result div wont show himself(i need some sort of callback?)

**EDIT**
No need for me to post my controller action, if I cut the jquery code who hides the result div, the partial view is visible(when i clicked on a link in my table ofc), but i need the code to hide that div, so it isn't there before anyone clicked on a link in my table.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="ContentDiv">
    <table id="table_id" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Naam)
                </th>
                <th>Persoonlijke Fiche
                </th>
                <th>Functiebeschrijving
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Naam)
                    <td>
                        @Ajax.ActionLink("Persoonlijke Fiche", "PersoonlijkeFichePartial", new { account = item.Account }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result"})
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Functiebeschrijving", "Details", new { account = item.Account })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="generate" class="ContentDiv">
    <div id="result"></div>
</div>



@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#table_id').dataTable({
                "aoColumns": [{ "bSortable": true }, { "bSortable": false }, {     "bSortable": false }]
            }
                );
        });
        $(function () {
            if ($("div#result").html() == "") {
                $("div#generate").hide();
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Is it just me or does asp.net really make a complete muddle out of simple stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try editing you code like this:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#table_id').dataTable({
                "aoColumns": [{ "bSortable": true }, { "bSortable": false }, {     "bSortable": false }]
            });
            toggleResultDiv()
        });

        function toggleResultDiv() {
            if ($("div#result").html() == "") {
                $("div#generate").hide();
            }
            else $("div#generate").show();
        }
    </script>
```

and change your ajax call like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Persoonlijke Fiche", "PersoonlijkeFichePartial", new { account = item.Account }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result", OnSuccess = "toggleResultDiv"})
```

You need to call your function that shows or hides div. In your case it's called only once and always hides `div#generate`